# C: read binary file into struct

Tags: c, file, struct, ip, readfile

**SOLVED BELOW**

I'm writing an IP forwarding program and I'm trying to read the header data.

I have structs for different lines such as this for the first line:

```
struct line1 {
  char a; //version
  char b; //header length
  unsigned short c; //datagram length
};
```

The different data types are dependent on the length of the data field.

I have variable initialization:

```
struct line1 l1 = {};
FILE *ip_packets, *routing_table;
```

My professor showed a simple read function that was something like `read(ip_packets, 4, l1)`  (4 Bytes) that automatically put the data into the struct fields. I have searched around the web and haven't found a simple method like this. What read function am I looking for?

I've tried `fscanf` in this way:

```
  if (fscanf(ip_packets, "%c %c %hu", &l1.a, &l1.b, &l1.c)){
    printf("%c\n", l1.a);
    printf("%c\n", l1.b);
    printf("%hu\n", l1.c);
  }
```

I've also tried syntaxt `%c,%c,%hu` or `%c/%c/%hu`

but that just prints:

```
Kendalls-Mac-mini:Programming 2 kendallweihe$ ./ip_read
E

0
```

**SOLUTION**

Turns out I was reading it in correctly, but I needed to print the integer value. My testing verification is in terms of integers. Easy enough.

**BETTER SOLUTION**

```
fread(&l1, 4, 1, ip_packets);
```